# how to expand output in GitLab CI/CD job?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I've setup a job that run some PowerShell commands. One them returns JSON object.
however when I open Job log I see only part of the object. How I can see the full object?

```
{@{productNo=1; onTarget=f944fb79-b39f-4936-b0b6-8eef3c802014; name=asdffgh-as…
```

Comment: What version of GitLab and GitLab Runner are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Write the output to a file, then store the file as an artifact:

```
script:
  - your_command | Out-File -FilePath output.json
artifacts:
  paths:
    - output.json
```

See [Using Out-File](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-send-output-to-a-file/#using-out-file), and [Job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html).

Comment: I just want to have it listed in Stdout, where it will be pickup by another service.

Comment: Ok, no need to pipe the output to a file, then. Just run `your_command`